# Application Insights auto install broke parts of .NET website

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure-application-insights

When working on getting Application Insights into a website that had been around for a long time (quite legacy), it all worked super smooth. I was able to follow the auto installer in Visual Studio and it all seemed to happen seamlessly. But, when I started to use the website a few weeks later, a few small issues started cropping up that were hard to explain. They were very specific to the application being worked on and in our case affected cookies on the site. There are a lot of files, settings and boilerplate code added when Application Insights is installed so the question is what are common failure points that developers need to be aware of when letting the installer add Application Insights to a site.

Answer (score 2):

Application Insights auto installer adds the file `Web/FilterConfig.cs` to your .NET project by default. This looks like the following.

```
using System.Web.Mvc

namespace Project.Web
{
    public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
    {
        filters.Add(new ErrorHandler.AiHandleErrorAttribute());
    }
{
```

The problem with this is that it does not check if you have an existing `FilterConfig.cs` file anywhere else in the project. So, if you have one lower down in scope that is being loaded, the framework will ignore it and instead only load the one provided by Application Insights. For an older application that relies on this file, it creates a hidden issue if not covered by good tests. By merging the filter add line with our existing FilterConfig, the problem was resolved and everything went back to normal. Hope this helps others in the future figure out issues with installing AI in their application.